# Frontend-framework overrides whole css

Tags: html, css, frameworks, components, materialize

I am using Material Light Design but want to include **some** components/css-classes of materializecss.

When I includ it via CDN at the beginning of the index.html like this:

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

it overrides and changes the whole style of the website, so that it looks very buggy/wrong. For example the header bar is completly overriden:

[image]

How can I include materializecss and **only** use some components, like [image-enlargement](https://materializecss.com/media.html), withouth messing up the whole website OR having to override every single css class I don't want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might have been a mistake in the order of the files you have  included at the top. Try reordering the CSS file by putting material light design's CSS file first.

If thats not the case then the two libraries may have the same class name so i suggest you use SASS to use the specific components u need from materializecss. more on this here, under the SASS setup section : https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you're asking is possible. A CSS file is all or nothing, but one thing to note is that it will use the most specific/most recent rule given. Keeping this in mind, you can either:

**a)** write CSS that cancels out the bits that are messing up your site

or

**b)** write CSS that takes place of the bits you want from the **materializecss** file

Whichever is less work. Be sure to import your own CSS *after* this other file.